# What is the regex that properly splits SVG 'd' attributes into tokens?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split the `d` attribute on a path tag in an svg file into tokens.

This one is relatively easy:

```
d = "M 2 -12 C 5 15 21 19 27 -2 C 17 12 -3 40 5 7"
tokens = d.split(/[\s,]/)
```

But this is also a valid `d` attribute:

```
d = "M2-12C5,15,21,19,27-2C17,12-3,40,5,7"
```

The tricky parts are letters and numbers are no longer separated and negative numbers use only the negative sign as the separator. How can I create a regex that handles this?

The rules seem to be:

- split wherever there is white space or a comma
- split numerics from letters (and keep "-" with the numeric)

I know I can use lookaround, for example:

```
tokens = pathdef.split(/(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)/)
```

I'm having trouble forming a single regex that also splits on the minus signs *and keeps the minus sign with the numbers*.

The above code should tokenize as follows:

```
[ 'M', '2', '-12', 'C', '5', '15', '21', '19', '27', '-2', 'C', '17', '12', '-3', '40', '5', '7' ]
```

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: I'm doing it in JS, but it ought to be similar in any language.

Comment: It's not pure regex but a really easy way would be to replace all the "-" with " -" (space then minus) and then just split how you were

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Brief

Unfortunately, **JavaScript doesn't allow lookbehinds**, so your options are fairly limited and the regex in the **Other Regex Engines** section below will not work for you (albeit it will with some other regex engines).

#### Other Regex Engines

**Note**: The regex in this section (*Other Regex Engines*) will not work in Javascript. See the JavaScript solution in the **Code** section instead.

I think with your original regex you were trying to get to:

```
[, ]|(?<![, ])(?=-|(?<=[a-z])\d|(?<=\d)[a-z])
```

This regex allows you to split on those matches (`,` or , or locations that are followed by `-`, or locations where a letter precedes a digit or locations where a digit precedes a letter).

---

### Code

```js
var a = [
  "M 2 -12 C 5 15 21 19 27 -2 C 17 12 -3 40 5 7",
  "M2-12C5,15,21,19,27-2C17,12-3,40,5,7"
]

var r = /-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+|[a-z]/gi

a.forEach(function(s){
  console.log(s.match(r));
});
```

---

### Explanation

- `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[a-z]` Match either of the following

  - `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

    - `-?` Match `-` literally zero or one time

      - `(?:\d*\.)?` Match the following zero or one time

        - `\d*` Match any number of digits
        - `\.` Match a literal dot
    - `\d+` Match one or more digits
  - `[a-z]` Match any character in the range from `a-z` (any lowercase alpha character - since `i` modifier is used this also matches uppercase variants of those letters)

I added `(?:\d*\.)?` because (to the best of my knowledge) you can have decimal number values in SVG `d` attributes.

**Note**: Changed the original regex portion of `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to `(?:\d*\.)?\d+` in order to catch numbers that don't have the whole number part such as `.5` as per [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas) (see comments below question).

Comment: Thanks for also catching those decimals.

Comment: @Octopus I added more details to my answer. I posted the regex that I think you were originally trying to attain. You could use that regex to split on, but it won't work in regex engines that don't support `\d` or lookbehinds.

Comment: better `/-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+|[a-z]/gi` because something like `L.5.25` is also valid and means `L 0.5 0.25`

Comment: @Thomas thanks! I've updated my answer to include your logic. I've given proper credits in the end **Note**

Answer (score 1):

You could go for

```
-?\d+|[A-Z]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/iPyTrl/1/).

---

Here, instead of *splitting*, you could very well just *match them*:

```
matches = "M 2 -12 C 5 15 21 19 27 -2 C 17 12 -3 40 5 7".match(/-?\d+|[A-Z]/g)
# matches holds the different tokens
```